# Grouping data that has specific values

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, maybe my title may not be accurate. Hopefully reading this you can understand what I'm trying to do.

What I am trying to do is: I have a certain district loaded into the table "walksheet_1" All I want to do is take houses that are purely democrats and republicans (1 or more person is that party) I dont want houses with a DEM and a NPP or REP and a DS... just DEMs and REPs.. I will attach the code I have below:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name,
CONCAT(house_number, " ", street_name, " ", street_suffix, " ", unit_number, " ") AS Address
site_city AS City, site_state AS State, site_zip AS Zip, phone, email, PAV, party, HHKey

FROM walksheet_1

WHERE
(party LIKE 'DEM' OR party LIKE 'REP')

GROUP BY
HHKey;
```

Group by statement is added to group by household. I want to pick out the data on households, not all specific voters.

Thank you!!

Comment: Why you have used `GROUP BY HHKey;` ? Just remove `GROUP BY` clause you'l get output. I don't think you need `GROUP BY` in your query.

Comment: please post some sample data and table in http://sqlfiddle.com and the expected result to the question.

Comment: group by is added to group people by their households. I want to select only households, not every voter. Thats why the GROUP BY HHKey is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naive solution:

```
select group_concat(first_name), group_concat(last_name),
CONCAT(house_number, " ", street_name, " ", street_suffix, " ", unit_number, " ") AS Address,
group_concat(distinct party) as parties
from walksheet_1 
group by Address
having parties in ('DEM','REP');
```

If you get in trouble with performance (big number of votes), just create a table with adresses and three columns 'REP','DEM','OTHER'. Each time you insert into walksheet_1, just check for that adress if it is something new for that adress.

I very much wonder how you could know the votes (isn't democracy supposed to have some secrets?) and if you only know those small houses where only one first_name and one last_name lives (in the house where I live we have 12 last_names at four floors, and I have read in a book that even bigger houses have been built by humans). What you want to achieve with the names you have to decide, just remember: there might be more than one per house.